Acme4j Http01Challenge failing because mismatch of tokens after update operation
Help with this. I was assigned this task and it's my first time working with ACME4J. The report says that a jks file isn't being generated, but this is a process that happens after the validation against the Acme server. But the challenge is failing saying that the tokens for the challenge doesn't match, but until the update execution, the token is the same as the expected by the server.
My domain is: editdb.rwscheckout.com
I ran this command:
challenge.trigger();

// attempt to pass the test 6 times (we only wanna spend about 30 secs total for
// each account)
for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
{
    challenge.update();
    // If the status is invalid, something went wrong, so it should be investigated
if ( challenge.getStatus() == Status.VALID || challenge.getStatus() == Status.INVALID )
    break;
    Thread.sleep(5_000);
}

if ( challenge.getStatus() == Status.VALID )
{
    ACME_LETS_ENCRYPT_STREAM.println(prefix + "challenge passed for account: " + 
            domain);
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}

It produced this output:
json response: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge. Expected "D-EZIRAQejzL7GWS7IPR8d1Lc8c85Hs7MKTcEqz8grI.cWGMCIOzT7u8CnLd213wJQv_nSa9TZqPskPj3skx5BQ" (got "ksYprfcSgvybAGcksLu0IYKr4RN5v66v9VS3DJQvWTw.cWGMCIOzT7u8CnLd213wJQv_nSa9TZqPskPj3skx5BQ")
I can't login to a root shell on my machine or access the Acme server.
Help will be very appreciated.
I already tried deleting the update instruction, and update the version of the library to the most recent, but I don't know why my application keeps using version 2.12.
